# Randomly generate specific strings in C#

Tags: c#, random, generator

This is the first time I'm writing a C# code.

In my C# code, I need to generate a string that can be any of these:
`"00000041"`, `"0000424E"`, `"00004244"`, `"00004D53"`

How can you do this? How can you specify strings and randomly generate anyone from them?

Comment: So you just need to randomly pick from those 4 strings?

Comment: If you need to randomly generate one of predefined strings - then as possible option you can store them in array and randomly generate index to pick string.

Comment: You will need to give the rule used for generating the strings. It is impossible to know the rule from just examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] s1 = new string[4] { "00000041", "0000424E", "00004244", "00004D53" };
Random rnd = new Random();
int randIndex = rnd.Next(0,4);
var randomString = s1[randIndex];
```

Answer (score 3):

this selects randomly one string out of the list of predefined strings

```
Random rnd= new Random();
List<string> validStrings= new List<string>() {
 "00000041", 
 "0000424E", 
 "00004244", 
 "00004D53" };
string result = validStrings[rnd.Next(0, validStrings.Count)];
```